# Order multi-index dataframe and select top 10 by date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I select the Top 10 coins (by descending order) of the below dataframe for each given day?

[image]

I am attaching a code sample for generating a dummy sample

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD', 'XRP-USD']:
    ticker = yf.Ticker(i)
    data = ticker.history(period="max")
    data.reset_index('Date', inplace=True)
    data['value'] = np.random.random_sample()
    data['coin'] = i
    data.drop(columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Dividends', 'Stock Splits'], inplace=True)
    data.columns = ['date', 'coin', 'value']
    data.set_index(['date', 'coin'], inplace=True)
    df = df.append(data)
```

I am looking for an output format like :

| date | Coins |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-10-10 | [bitcoin, ethereum, polkadot, ..] |
| 2020-10-11 | [polkadot, ethereum, tether, ..] |

Comment: Will you please show a _text_ sample of your dataframe? I can't copy/paste from an image.

Comment: not sure how to do that really - it's a multiindex dataframe with one column

Comment: `print(df.reset_index().head().to_dict)` @Vasilis - I can figure out the rest.

Comment: I've attached the code to generate a sample instead

Comment: Does my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
df['value'].groupby(level=0).nlargest(10).reset_index(level='coin')['coin'].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Comment: I think this should be it, but missing the last step of getting the top 10 in a list - please refer to my last update in the description. Thanks!

Comment: And please consider going through [your list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6131860/vasilis?tab=questions) and accept answers that solved your problem. It helps the community (and yourself!) immensely for several reasons.

Comment: Quick follow up - any thoughts on how I can specify the grouping frequency (60d instead of daily for example)?